# Display Report Through the form

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I need to create Xtra _report and Devexpress report. I need the VB.NEt code to display the report through the form

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1115360)

Comment: There’s tons of good examples, documentation and demo apps in the DevExpress support site, and if still stuck they are really helpful if you post a question on their support forums

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dim Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(" Select * from XX  where XX LIKE '%" & XX.Text & "%'", Con)
    Dim Ds As New DataSet
        Dim RptAtt As New Inv
        Adp.Fill(Ds)
        Dim Dt = Ds.Tables(0)
        If Dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("XXX", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "XX")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        RptAtt.DataSource = Dt
        RptAtt.DataAdapter = Adp
        RptAtt.DataMember = "DataTable1"
        'RptAtt.RequestParameters = False
        Dim Tool_Report As ReportPrintTool = New ReportPrintTool(RptAtt)
        RptAtt.CreateDocument()
        Dim Frm As New Rep_Inv
        Frm.DocumentViewer1.DocumentSource = RptAtt
        Frm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).